# Why am I getting a "font error" after installing WPS-Office via flatpak?

Tags: fonts, flatpak, wps-office

I have installed WPS-Office from https://flathub.org.

When I open WPS-Office an error message is shown saying: `Some formula symbols might not be displayed correctly due to missing fonts symbol`.

Now, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fonts you need are available in a zip file that can be downloaded from:

- ArchLinux: [ttf-wps-fonts](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-wps-fonts/)

Alternatively, you can try installing the WPS `deb` package from [linux.wps.com](https://linux.wps.com/). It did not generate any font errors when I tried it.

Answer (score 2):

You can download those fonts from this link.

https://github.com/IamDH4/ttf-wps-fonts

Answer (score 0):

### Other ways of installing fonts:

### Way 1: (Installing a desired font)

##### Step 1:

Download fonts (****.ttf files***) from [fonts.google.com](https://fonts.google.com/) and paste those in **/usr/share/fonts**

##### Step 2:

From terminal:

```
fc-cache -r
```

---

### Way 2: (Installing common fonts)

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this sample problem after downloading the installation package (.deb) from the WPS Office site.

After searching online for a solution without success, I created on on my GitHub for anyone who was dealing with a similar issue.

the error was pointing to some missing font files. I already collated this files and also explained how to move them to the WPS font folder in the link below.

[wps missing fonts fix](https://github.com/iykrichie/WPS-Missing-Fonts)

Comment: Please write the necessary steps in the answer instead of linking out to a different website. The fix is not so lengthy that copying the steps is impractical.